# Display search bar and search button inline with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a little website ([link](https://waternear.me/)) which displays a search bar in the navigation bar. I'm using Bootstrap 4 for the navigation bar controls, and [Algolia Places](https://community.algolia.com/places/documentation.html) for the search bar HTML input element. The problem is that I cannot align the search bar with the search button, even though I'm using `form-inline`. Also, the search results displayed when typing something in the search bar get cut off.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Drinking Fountains</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Map
          <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>  
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>         

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="mr-sm-2"  id="address-bar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>              
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#navbarMenu .form-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

... should do the trick.

or, using Bootstrap flex utility classes:

```
<form class="d-flex align-items-center flex-nowrap">
```

---

But, to also resolve the `border-radius` issue, you might want to change your markup to:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="address-bar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <div class="input-group-append">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to add a little spacing between the search bar and button?

Comment: @Cesare, you can either give the button `ml-3` (or `ml-2` - smaller) or give the `<input>` a class of `mr-3` (or `mr-2` - smaller). Read more about Bootstrap's [spacing utilities here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/). But I'd go with the `input-group` version which I just added to the answer.

Comment: I'll accept because of the CSS at the top, but the HTML in your updated answer isn't fixing the alignment on my side.

Comment: Show me what alignment issue you have and I'll tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I think you forgot to close the form tag

Comment: I've updated the website with your same exact HTML code, but it appears skewed, I don't know why

Comment: You need to wrap the `<form>` inside a `<nav class="navbar">`. See [examples here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#forms). Also give it class `ml-auto` to push it to the right. [Here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORFqZ.png) what you should get.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `<button>` is `display:inline-block`. And your input has `max-width:100%` instead of `width:100%`.

Also your `.ap-dropdown-menu` isn't Z-indexed properly above the map.

Answer (score 1):

using Bootstrap:

wrap your `<span>` where search is and button with `<div class="d-flex"></div>`, and add to `<span>` class mr-2 for space you want.

Should be something like this:

`<div class="d-flex">
    <span class="algolia-places mr-2" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; direction: ltr;"> *other your code* </span>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>`

and

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vKda.png)